# Get specific key value in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my string:

```
var a = "Welcome to angular js";
```

I am using `split()` function to return its array:

```
console.log(a.split(" "));
```

But I don't need array, I want only 'angular' word.

```js
var a = "welcome to angular js"
console.log(a.split(" "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Any one help me here?

Comment: So `a.split(" ")[2]`

Comment: `console.log('angular')`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to check if "angular" exists?

Comment: yes, angular is exit. but don't need an array, i want return only string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code,

```
var a = "welcome to angular js"

console.log(a.split(" ")[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks @sathyanarayanan.

Answer (score 4):

You can split your string to array of strings and then iterate through the array to check if any of the elements matches the value you are looking for:

```
var a = "Welcome to angular js";
var b = a.split(" ");

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if(b[i] == 'angular') {
            console.log(b[i]);
        }
}
```

This way, you want have to specify which element of the array contains 'angular', the code will do all the work for you.